# ViewPager Fragment creating

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager

I have a `ViewPager` with 2 `Fragment`s. My question is: when will the `ViewPager` create the `Fragment`s? Because if I try to run some methods from my activity like:

```
MainFragment mf = (MainFragment) mPagerAdapter.getItem(0);
mf.setValues("blah");
```

In debug mode I can see that `mf` has been created and there is ID for it, but `onCreate()` method has not been called and my view is `null` but `mf` has the ID = `xxxxxxx`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`getItem(int position)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v13/app/FragmentPagerAdapter.html#getItem%28int%29) or [`instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v13/app/FragmentPagerAdapter.html#instantiateItem%28android.view.ViewGroup,%20int%29) methods of the [`FragmentPagerAdapter`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v13/app/FragmentPagerAdapter.html) returns new instance of the `Fragment` used by a `ViewPager`.